# How can I create an Image SlideShow(horizontal) in React Native using React Hooks(useState etc...)?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

How can I create an automatically timed slideshow (horizontally).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using this library you can create slideshow
"react-native-image-slider-box"
Working Example: https://snack.expo.io/@msbot01/d5a028

```
    export default class App extends React.Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          images: [
            "https://source.unsplash.com/1024x768/?nature",
            "https://source.unsplash.com/1024x768/?water",
            "https://source.unsplash.com/1024x768/?girl",
            "https://source.unsplash.com/1024x768/?tree"
          ]
        };
      }
      render() {
        return (
          <View style={styles.container}>
            <SliderBox
              autoplay={true}
              circleLoop={true}
              images={this.state.images}
              onCurrentImagePressed={index => console.warn(`image ${index} pressed`)}
              currentImageEmitter={index => console.warn(`current pos is: ${index}`)}
            />
          </View>
        );
      }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, but it never loop back to the first image once the slide is end
Can you please show me the SliderBox component here?
So that I can check the internal working for it

Comment: Just add "circleLoop={true}" in SliderBox
updated the example

Answer (score 0):

In this example I am going to be building our slider to be the full height and width of the browser to make things easy.

**Slider Component**

```
 import React, { useState } from 'react'
 /**
 * @function Slider
 */
const Slider = () => {
return 
 <div>
   {/*  */}
 </div>
 }

export default Slider
```

**Styling The Slider Component**

I’ve broken down my solution below.

- Slider will create a container set to whatever dimensions we want, which in our example will be 100% of the height and width of the browser.
- SliderContent will be used to house all of our slides, and will be designed to overflow Slider horizontally,. This will allow us to place all of the slides except the currently active one off screen.

Now that you have a skeleton solution, please go through this article on **React Slider: How To Build A Slider With React Hooks.**

https://medium.com/@ItsMeDannyZ/build-an-image-slider-with-react-es6-264368de68e4

Hope this will help.